# JAVA urlconnection.getoutputstream() taking inconsistent time for the same request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, urlconnection

I'm implementing a connection to an AWS( amazon web services ) instance of Elastic Search in order to send requests. I'm using the connection.getOutputStream() function to set up the connection. Although the code works perfectly, the time taken by it inconsistent. Making the getOutputStream() call takes time varying from less than 1 second to around 10 seconds for the same request.

Comment: Write an angry letter to amazon? - Try to verify, that the problem is not your java code, using soapUI or something like that...

Comment: From the log messages, the connection.getOutputStream() function seems to be the one taking time ( few milliseconds to max of around 10 seconds ) which is a single line of code. Don't think can make much adjustments to it. Angry letter to amazon seems to be the only way ahead.